# How to get a Drop down populated with sheet names to fill range of sheet cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi I hope someone can help.

I have a workbook column A is populated with titles leaving column B for data.
There is only these 2 columns in use.

I have the same titles in column A replicated on a series of sheets with column B filled out with client data.

On my first sheet (no data in column B) I'm attempting to use a single drop-down populated with the names given to the sheets on my workbook. 
When a sheet name is selected from the drop-down This is to fill in the data from the corresponding sheet. 
It's worth noting that all the titles are in the same cells on each sheet.

I can amalgamate all the client data onto one sheet if it's required for a solution but require one set of the data from a single drop-down on a separate sheet

I thought I might manage this with with some kind of range Vlookup linked to a separate sheet with the individual sheet names but i can't get my head round it. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Generally I use formulas in excel so if it's possible with VLookup or similar that's great if not then please drop some code for VBA.

Comment: Indirect should work for you.
`=VLOOKUP(B1,INDIRECT(A2&"!A:C"),3,0)`, this example the worksheet name would be located in cell A2.

Comment: Hi Having difficulty getting this to work.  Only have 2 columns on each sheet column A titles and B being the data. the formula references columns A:C? and set 3? I've tried altering this but it's not coming out.

Comment: I was just showing you how to use `indirect`. `INDIRECT(A2&"!A:C"),` A2 is has the name of the sheet. A:C was just an example. I don't know what your ranges are in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, Sheet11 is a customer data sheet and looks like this ...

[image]

The sheet that is looking up customer data looks like this ...

[image]

Cell D2 contains the drop down list to choose which customer data sheet to look at, in this case Sheet11.

Cell B2 contains the following formula, filled down...

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&$D$2&"'!"&"A:B"),2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&$D$2&"'!"&"A:B"),2,FALSE))
```

It constructs a string representing the customer data to look in, and uses the INDIRECT function to convert that string into a valid reference. It uses VLookup to find the data of interest. If VLookup returns an error, a null string is returned, otherwise the customer data is returned.

Note: When constructing the string, the sheet name is enclosed in single quotes, in the event there is a space in the sheet name.